# Apache symlink to directory on Raid Drive [not working]

Tags: permissions, symlink, raid

I have a Debian install.  It's not my first (but third server, without counting multiple raspberry hanging round)

Let say my user is named "user1"

Novelty for me, I have a

- a first disk hosting / directory as well as home for user1
- a software Raid1 composed of two other disks, mounted with mdamd inside
  /media/raidMount

I have apache2 running as "www-data". www-data is a member of user1 group.
Inside my apache site enable conf I have this directive

```
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
```

I also have a symbolic link inside /var/www to /home/user1/Share1 named share1
When i browse to my localhost i can see share1 directory and browse into it. Till here all is well.

**Now I tried to make a symbolic link to /media/raidMount/Share2
I cannot see it, and get no error by apache2.**

I shall also add that
/media/raidMount/  is fully owned by user1:user1 and with 754 permissions
and mounted in fstab as
/dev/md0        /media/raidMount ext4    defaults

I had similar setup in the past but the drive wasn't software raid.
I think permissions / ownership are set correctly. Is there some reasons for a raid to be seen differently by apache or by linux symbolic links?
What I missing?  Maybe mount options?

Thanks for your insights !

Comment: `0754` permissions on a directory are unusual but can have some specific purposes. Does changing the perms to `0755` make any difference? Apache has no dependency on the file systems (mostly) or the hardware for the directories it serves. Being on a software raid instead of a physical disk or nfs mount will not affect apache's operation.

Comment: No, I tried all kind.  The problem seems to be elsewhere. I can imagine that apache does not care, but apparently it does not have access (read or write) to the simlink pointing to a directory on the raid disk. So I am stuck.